# How to QUERY (ImportRange) if the "where" clause also uses imported values?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language, importrange

I am trying to query ImportRange data by the condition that a column matches a value from the imported spreadsheet, but it does not work:

```
=Query(importRange("KEY1","namesheet1!A2:R1600"), "select Col4 where Col7 = (importRange("KEY1","namesheet2!F108:F108"))  ",0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
"select Col4 where Col7 = (importRange("KEY1","namesheet2!F108:F108"))  "
```

by

```
"select Col4 where Col7 = " & importRange("KEY1","namesheet2!F108")
```